# Is there a way to normalize a Caffe Blob along a certain dimension?

Tags: c++, neural-network, normalization, caffe, blas

I've got a blob with the shape n * t * h * w (Batch number, features, height, width). Within a Caffe layer I want to do an L1 normalization along the t axis, i.e. for fixed n, h and w the sum of values along t should be equal to 1. Normally this would be no big deal, but since it's within a Caffe layer it should happen very quickly, preferably through the Caffe math functions (based on BLAS). Is there a way to achieve this in an efficient manner?

I unfortunately can't change the order of the shape parameters due to later processing, but I can remove the batch number (have a vector of blobs with just t * h * w) or I could convert the blob to an OpenCV Mat, if it makes things easier.

Edit 1: I'm starting to suspect I might be able to solve my task with the help of caffe_gpu_gemm, where I'd multiply a vector of ones of length t with a blob from one batch of shape t * h * w, which should theoretically give me the sums along the feature axis. I'll update if I figure out the next step.